# Dynamics OR filtering with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a list  of of SQLAlchemy Model attributes. For example:

`my_list = ['firstName', 'lastName']`

I also have a person SQLAlchemy Object with `firstName and lastName` attributes.

I want to search query my database for people with a query as follows:
`session.filter( Person.lastName.like(query+'%') | Person.firstName.like(query+'%')).all()`

The tricky part is that I want to generate the above filter dynamically from the `my_list` list. For example if an `emailAddress` is added to the list I want the query to also search via the objects email property.

Answer (score 1):

With SQLAlchemy this is pretty easy if you know about [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce); use `getattr` to get the dynamically named column from the `Person` class.

```
from functools import reduce  # python 3
from operator import or_

columns = [ 'firstName', 'lastName' ]

# make a list of `Person.c.like(query+'%')`
likes = [ getattr(Person, c).like(query+'%') for c in column ]

# join them with | using reduce; does the same as likes[0]|likes[1]|....
final_filter = reduce(or_, likes)

session.filter(final_filter).all()
```

Though `or_` also accepts any number of clauses to `or` together, so you can use argument unpacking too:

```
 final_filter = or_(*likes)
```

Comment: Just to note for anyone hunting, you can use this approach for creating a list of conditions and passing them to the filter function. Something like: `filters = [Reservation.start_date > req.start, Reservation.end_date <= req.end]`. Then, `conditions = reduce(and_, filters)`. Finally, `db.session.query(Reservation).filter(conditions).all()`. The advantage to this is that you can conditionally add filters in a cleaner fashion.